# Como faço para pegar a informação selecionada pelo usuário e atribuí-la a uma variável?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 Selecione o veiculo:<select id="Carros" onChange="Carro()">
                                <option value="U">Up! 1.0 
                                <option value="A">Argo 1.0
                                <option value="K">Ka SE Plus 1.0          
                                <option value="S">Sandero Zen 1.0
                                <option value="H">HB20 Comfort Plus</select><p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou listar pra você algumas formas de fazer isso.

**Usando a função onchange()**

```js
        function carro() {
            var carros = document.getElementById("carros");
            var result = carros.options[carros.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(result)
        }
```

```html
Selecione o veiculo: <select id="carros" onChange="carro()">
        <option value="Up">Up! 1.0 </option>
        <option value="Argo">Argo 1.0</option>
        <option value="Ka" selected>Ka SE Plus 1.0 </option>        
        <option value="Sandero">Sandero Zen 1.0</option>
        <option value="Hb20">HB20 Comfort Plus</option>
   </select>
```

Usei sua sugestão da propriedade onchange().Esse evento ocorre sempre que o valor do elemento em questão for alterado.

É importante você ter em mente que programar requer seguir algumas boas práticas também. Por exemplo, você *carros* ao invés de Carros e carro() ao invés de Carro(). Você pode seguir o padrão que você quiser para nomear variáveis e funções, mas lembre-se que em outros contextos um padrão para nomenclatura pode ser exigido. **Também é uma boa prática fechar as tags html**.

**Usando um addEventListener**

```js
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const select = document.getElementById("carros");
            alert(select.selectedIndex)
        });
```

```html
Selecione o veiculo: 
        <select id="carros">
          <option value="U">Up! 1.0</option> 
          <option value="A">Argo 1.0</option>
          <option value="K" selected>Ka SE Plus 1.0</option>          
          <option value="S">Sandero Zen 1.0</option>
          <option value="H">HB20 Comfort Plus</option>
        </select>
```

Neste exemplo, o script emite um alerta para exibir os elementos marcados como *selected*. Você pode adaptá-lo para ter a mesma função do primeiro exemplo. Ele faz isso registrando uma espera de evento a um elemento alvo, ou seja, ao select#carros.

**Caso você queira usar um select multiple**

```js
var carros = document.getElementById("carros");
        var selecionado = []
        for(var i = 0; i < carros.length; i++) {
            if(carros[i].getAttribute('selected') !== null)  {
                selecionado.push(carros[i].value)
            }            
        }
        alert(selecionado)
```

```html
Selecione o veiculo: <select id="carros" multiple>
        <option value="U" selected>Up! 1.0 </option>
        <option value="A">Argo 1.0</option>
        <option value="K" selected>Ka SE Plus 1.0 </option>         
        <option value="S">Sandero Zen 1.0</option>
        <option value="H">HB20 Comfort Plus</option>
    </select>
```

Neste exemplo, `carros[i].getAttribute('selected') !== null` verifica o estado do atributo *selected*. Se você der um `console.log(carros[i].getAttribute('selected'))` vai ver que o resultado ou é `null` ou   `""` (string vazia). Com um typeof você percebe que retorna null (object) e "" (string).

**Você pode ver estes links para te ajudar:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener